# Submit Post Data Without a Form in ASP Classic/VBScript

Tags: jquery, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm using ASP classic and I'd like to submit post data without actually having a form.

Here's the scenario. The user fills out a comment box in a form on Page1. The form uses Post to submit the data for Page2. Page2 processes the incoming data and redirects back to Page1 using the Response.Redirect method. If the user has filled out something incorrectly I need to post this data back to Page1 so the user does not lose what he has typed. Page2 is not intended to actually display any HTML at any time. It's merely used as a comment processing page and always redirects no matter what. Is there a better or preferred way of doing this?

jQuery has the .post method which allows you to do what I'm asking for. However, I'm really not sure how I'd integrate this with my ASP page. I supposed I'd actually have to display an HTML page momentarily and then have jQuery handle the redirect after the page is loaded. This also means that I'd have a form with values which jQuery would extract. I think this would probably be an OK work-around but I'd prefer a more "native" solution if one exists.

Comment: Correct design would be to have AJAX in the first place meaning in Page1 - have AJAX post the data to Page2, and handle the response. This is big change though, so if you're tight on time, check the workaround suggested by Yots below.

Comment: An other option when you want to avoid AJAX is to handle state on Page1 and call Page2 from Page1 with ServerXMLHTTP. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766431(v=vs.85).aspx. With ServerXMLHTTP you can use POST to send your variables to Page2.

Comment: jQuery is the better solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your system `Server.Transfer()` could be a solution.
So when you do a Server.Tranfer() from Page2 to Page1 all your data is there again.

From the docs:

> The Transfer method sends (transfers) all the state information (all
>   application/session variables and all items in the request
>   collections) created in one ASP file to a second ASP file.
>
> When the second ASP page completes its tasks, it will NOT return to
>   the first ASP page (like the Execute method).
>
> Note: The Transfer method is an efficient alternate for the
>   Response.Redirect. A redirect forces the Web server to handle an extra
>   request while the Server.Transfer method transfers execution to a
>   different ASP page on the server, and avoids the extra round trip.

Comment: I think this is a pretty good solution although I haven't tested it yet. It's unclear to me how to handle "global" variables and constants, "global" connection objects, includes that the two pages might share in common, etc.